# Add a leading 0 to all records in one table

Tags: addition, leading-zero

I have nearly 17,000 book titles in a database. The ISBN field lost the leading 0. Is there any easy way to add this digit to all entries at once? ISBN should be 10 digits long, but all are only showing up with last 9.

Comment: What database system are you using?  What is the column type?  It could be something as simple as `UPDATE Table SET Field = '0' + Field`

Comment: What type of database? What kind of field is it (`INT`, `VARCHAR`, etc.)? Unless you give us specific details, we can't give you a specific answer.

Comment: This may not be as easy as I had hoped. The content was imported to WooCommerce in Wordpress via .csv file, then displayed using a template. the ID field that the isbn is in is called "Content" and the information comes from this piece of the template: {isbn[1]}

Comment: LONGTEXT - need to add lead 0 to isbn: 

FROM `wp_pmxi_templates`
   
Partial Texts
Rows  content
1  {sku[1]}   {author[1]}
{post_title[1]}
Publisher: {place[1]}   |   {publisher[1]}   |   {date[1]}
Edition:</strong>  {edition[1]}  First Edition: {el_st_edition[1]}
Description:{post_excerpt[1]}
Binding:</strong>  Hardback-{hardback[1]}   |    Dust Jacket-{dust_jacket[1]}   |   Paperback-{paperback[1]}   |   Autographed/Inscribed-{autographed_inscribed[1]}
Condition: {condition[1]}
Category:  {category[1]}   |   {sub_category[1]}
ISBN:</strong> {isbn[1]}
${regular_price[1]}

Comment: MYSQL Database
Field Type Collation Attributes Null Default Extra
 
id bigint(20)   UNSIGNED No  auto_increment
 
options text utf8_general_ci  Yes NULL 
 
scheduled varchar(64) utf8_general_ci  No  
 
name varchar(200) utf8_general_ci  No  
 
title text utf8_general_ci  Yes NULL 
 
content longtext utf8_general_ci  Yes NULL 
 
is_keep_linebreaks tinyint(1)   No 0 
 
is_leave_html tinyint(1)   No 0 
 
fix_characters tinyint(1)   No 0